# Sign in to Chromium 54 and 56 fails on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, chromium

After converting from Win 7 to Win 10, I am now unable to sign in to the online Chromium service from Chromium Version 54.0.2811.0 - looks like I am signed in, I provide the username and password which get me into gMail, and the following error message ensues, but I am not signed into Chromium and cannot sync the data I need.

> Can't sign in
>   Service unavailable; try again later.

I have tried clearing cache and cookies, reinstalling Chromium, and clearing sync data, all to no avail. Replacing Chromium with version 56.0.2917.0 also did not help.

Then, removed Chromium, and reinstalled using [Chocolatey](http://chromium.woolyss.com/#windows-64-bit-installer)
selecting the Synch version 56.0.2919.0 also to no avail.

Comment: You can enter a new bug for your problem by going to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Get More information at : http://www.chromium.org/chrome-release-channels

Hope this works

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=664828 no response

Comment: Try to disable the firewall and antivirus (for Defender disable real-time protection). I'm not sure I understand what is "the online Chromium service" - if this is Google then post the results of `chrome://signin-internals`.

Answer (score 1):

save all data and possibly image system as this might break things.

you can use something like [revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) to uninstall it and all traces of it. Then reboot run ccleaner to get rid of any orphaned registry entries. Might also want to clear out temp files. do another reboot then reinstall it using admin rights.

If that does not do it you can find the spot Chromium is trying to write to and give everyone access to that folder. Try finding the folder Chromium is trying to write to in the logs.

Answer (score -1):

Might be a bit odd, but are you logged to the Windows 10 with MS account?

You can try logging in under different local account, or [convert your current account](http://www.howtogeek.com/230543/how-to-revert-your-windows-10-account-to-a-local-one-after-the-windows-store-hijacks-it/) for that purpose and try running Chromium again.

Comment: Not using M$ login.